# Injecting configuration value into Helm Chart

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers, command-line-interface, kubernetes-helm

I am getting started building a Helm chart for a kube cluster I am deploying to AKS in Azure. I am building an AKS cluster with ARM templates, and I want to take the output of the ARM template (in this case an App Insights Key) and place it into my Chart so all my apps use that key in config. I am at a point where I can get the key from the template in the command line (using Azure CLI), but I am not sure how to get that key into my charts dynamically. I know I can use values.yaml for this, but the syntax I am struggling with. Is there command I need to pass into helm to do this, or some template binding syntax will do the trick.

Comment: I did not fully understand your question. Maybe `--set` flag what you need

Comment: I think it is, I am not sure where to put the placeholder for the set command to override

Comment: in Values.yaml file? :)

Comment: But which one, the root one?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this. I want to inject my build tag into values.yaml so that i can use it with release pipelines